# SVN isn't work properly since adding ShareKit 2.0 (as a subproject)

Tags: xcode, svn, git-svn, sharekit

I've been using SVN for my apps for over a year, never had any problem. When I add/edit/modify files in my projects, they will show the 'A' 'M' to show what you've done since last commit, which is great!

I recently added ShareKit to my project..they want you to install it as a subproject ShareKit Install steps.

After following all those steps and committing back to my SVN, now when I open my project in Xcode my main project file (the top thing in the tree with blue icon) and the MainWindow.xib file has a '?' beside them. And now when I add or edit files in my project, no 'M' or anything is shown beside the filename.

I can still commit correctly and the SVN knows what's been changed. It was just nice to be able to see what i've changed since my last commit/get in the code with the indicators beside the filenames.

Anyone have this problem or know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like XCode svn implementation is confused with included git submodule. I do not use SVN, so I can not help. However, if you will find some interesting info on this, you might make a short note in ShareKit's install wiki

Answer (score 0):

Sharekit comes from a git submodule. To fix this, delete the .git (invisible) files.

[How to show hidden files on mac](http://lifehacker.com/188892/show-hidden-files-in-finder)

Clean 'n run xcode project.
I had the same problem and this solved. ;)

dsa